# C# Windows Form displaying PDF file use Ppdfview4net (Display the first page only)

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I am using Ppdfview4net to display PDF file, the issue that I have and not able to find a solution the   Ppdfview4net display the first page only. However, when checking the PDF file it contains more than one page.

```
        public void LoadDocument(Stream fileNameStream, DisplayMode displayMode)
    {
        ShowHideLoaderForm(true);
        DisplayMode = displayMode;
        SetDisplayMode();
        pdfDocument.Load(fileNameStream);
        BindAnnotations();
        ShowHideLoaderForm(false);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PageLayout set in the PDF file is SinglePage so PDFView4NET displays a single page. You can switch between pages by setting the PageNumber property.

You can display all pages and navigate between them using the scrollbar if you set the PageDisplayLayout property on the viewer to OneColumn.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops [PDFView4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdfview4net/overview.htm).

Comment: It's working but I have issue in scrolling between pages "Can't Access closed stream". I am using PDFView4NET  to modify PDF file by adding different type of annotations. do you have any suggestion for this issue? @iPDFdev

Comment: If you load the PDFDocument from a stream you have to keep the stream open as long as you display the file as pages of document are loaded as needed. If this is not an option for you, you can set the PDFDocument.IncrementalLoad property to false before calling the Load method and you can close the stream next.